# Editor For Model

Tags: asp.net-mvc, attributes, editorfor

I am editing my model with @Html.EditorFor(m => Model....

I need to force one of the properties to be either Admin or user,

what attribute can I put over my model property to force a drop down box to appear with these 2 options?

Answer (score 0):

Create the following extension for Enums

```
public static class EnumExtensions
{
    public static IEnumerable<SelectListItem> ToSelectListItems<TEnum>(this TEnum enumObj)
    {
        var values = from TEnum e in Enum.GetValues(typeof(TEnum))
                     select new SelectListItem() { Value = e.ToString(), Text = Enum.GetName(typeof(TEnum), e) };

        return values;
    }
}
```

Then add the following custom editor template (under Views/Shared/EditorTemplates)

```
@model Enum

@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m, Model.ToSelectListItems())
```

Then make your property an enum with User and Administrator as Options.

You can also go as far as creating a custom attribute to add display names for enum values (to handle spaces etc).

Comment: how do you make the custom attribute?

Comment: @user1588670 - You wouldn't need to create a custom attribute for your entity - just use an enum as above, and the above code will create a dropdown for the enum options.  The custom attribute I mention above was referring to a custom attribute for the enum values themsleves, in case you wanted to change how they are displayed.

Comment: Although you are right you didn't answer my question. There are other reasons I want to use annotations. I don't want to change the controller or the model that is being passed I just want to add an annotation to the model.

Comment: There is no other way of doing it.  You can create your own custom annotations to do this, for sure, but you will still need to create custom editor templates to display the options in the browser.